# What this Visual Basic 6.0 code do?

Tags: vb6

What does this Visual Basic 6.0 code below do? However it has been used for a search function, I'm not clear with it. So please explain what it does.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim key As Integer, str As String
    key = InputBox("Enter the Employee No whose details u want to know: ")
    Set rs = Nothing
    str = "select * from emp where e_no=" & key
    rs.Open str, adoconn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    txtNo.Text = rs(0)
    txtName.Text = rs(1)
    txtCity.Text = rs(2)
    txtDob.Text = rs(4)
    txtPhone.Text = rs(3)
    Set rs = Nothing
    str = "select * from emp"
    rs.Open str, adoconn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm wondering about rs. It is set to nothing just before a method is called on it. I know that is legal, but it is normally frowned upon.

Comment: Ya that's the point i too got stucked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim key As Integer, str As String
    key = InputBox("Enter the Employee No whose details u want to know: ") ''// query the user for a name
    Set rs = Nothing
    str = "select * from emp where e_no=" & key ''//create sql query on the fly
    rs.Open str, adoconn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly ''// create a connection to an sql database
    txtNo.Text = rs(0) ''//assign the results of the query to input fields or labels
    txtName.Text = rs(1)
    txtCity.Text = rs(2)
    txtDob.Text = rs(4)
    txtPhone.Text = rs(3)
    Set rs = Nothing
    str = "select * from emp"
    rs.Open str, adoconn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic ''// creates a new sql connection and load the whole emp table
End Sub
```

Short summary: Ask the user for a name and display the data of the user in labels or textboxes.

Comment: and whats the reason rs have been declared as nothing ??is that must??

Comment: no, it is an instance variable declared outside the method. It simply resets the content to reuse it.

Comment: Then how does this line of code works? "txtNo.Text = rs(0)" , how it displays the emp_no correctly if it has been found?

Comment: `rs(0)` is the first field in the sql query. it works under the assumption that the first field in the emp table in the database is the employee number.

Comment: "[`Set rs = Nothing`] simply resets the content to reuse it" -- well, this is VB6 (your comment characters `//` are wrong :) so it simply reduces the reference count by one, therefore it will only "resets the content" if the reference count was one to begin with.

Comment: @Anto Aravinth: `txtNo.Text = rs(0)` is a contraction of `txtNo.Text = rs.Fields.Item(0).Value` because the default property of a `Recordset` is object is `Fields` (of type `Collection`), the default property of a `Collection` is `Item` (of type `Field`), and the default property of a `Field` is object is `Value`.

Answer (score 5):

The point no one yet has explicitly said is `rs` must be declared `As New RecordSet` so that the `Set rs = Nothing` just means effectively the same as `Set rs = New RecordSet`.

Comment: Maybe less of a gotcha than a "knowing what your coding is doing and why."  I can see this burning copy/paste coders pretty badly though.

Comment: @Bob By "gotcha", I mean it's an issue of "understanding your code and your language" that frequently traps less experienced VB6 programmers, so Ant's shouldn't necessarily feel stupid for missing this. You are correct to emphasise that anyone who's caught by this needs to do some learning (unless they don't want to continue to develop as a VB6 programmer).

Answer (score 1):

It makes two searches against the database. The result of the first search is used to populate some text boxes. The results of the second search... well I have no idea what they are doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks up data from a database based on a column called `e_no`, loads information from the found row into TextBox controls, and then re-queries the database for all `emp` rows.

Comment: Then how does this line of code works? "txtNo.Text = rs(0)" , how it displays the emp_no correctly if it has been found?